# Cronjob to add datestamp to file not running

Tags: cron, ubuntu-16.04

Good day everyone.

I have an issue, and Googling the issue has not helped me, basically I have the following requirement.

1. cronjob that runs 1st script, output is written to a file
2. file that is created, to have a date stamp
3. 2nd script executes, mail the generated file as an attachment

The issue is with adding the timestamp, if I set the cron to run and just create a file with a generic filename the cronjob runs fine.

I have tried the following:

```
0 8-17/1 * * * python /usr/local/bin/script1.py >> /usr/local/bin/file_`date +\%Y-%m-%d`.txt 2>&1 && python /usr/local/bin/email_script.py

0 8-17/1 * * * python /usr/local/bin/acme_transcoding_check.py >> /usr/local/bin/file_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").txt 2>&1 && python /usr/local/bin/email_script.py
```

Server is running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Use backtick (\`) in date, like `\`date +\%Y-%m-%d\``.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies, I also tried it like this:

0 8-17/1 * * * python /usr/local/bin/script1.py >> /usr/local/bin/file_`date +\%Y-%m-%d`.txt 2>&1

Comment: Aah, I see, you already did that. :-) Formatted example.

Comment: I don't think you specify the output-file. Is that correct?

Comment: basically, f the cronjob is set like this, it works fine:

0 8-17/1 * * * python /usr/local/bin/acme_transcoding_check.py >> /usr/local/bin/file.txt 2>&1

Comment: Pardon, did not read the line completely. Looks like you need to escape the percent sign. https://serverfault.com/questions/84430/whats-wrong-with-my-cronjob-syntax-im-trying-to-use-a-backtick

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, after escaping all the %'s, it looks to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the percent-sign (%) with a backslash as explained in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84430/whats-wrong-with-my-cronjob-syntax-im-trying-to-use-a-backtick) (not mine).

Comment: Hi kometen, because of recent comment elsewhere, NOT related at all to this question/answer here, I would to make sure that you know to flag the "most questionable kind of content" (avoiding the s-word here...), instead of close-voting.